# Return values from ionic2 modal to parent page

Tags: ionic2

I am opening a Modal in ionic2, to search the values from a list. After search, I want to get the selected values back in my parent screen.

```html
searchRooms(){
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(RoomSearch);
        modal.present();
  }
```

This opens my search Modal and there I have list of available rooms. If user click on any room then I want to return back the value to parent page. I am not sure how to do this.

From documentation I feel NavConroller.pop can be used to pass back the values but I don't know how to use that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `onDidDismiss` method explained in the [Modal Controller](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/).

In the page that opens your modal you can do :

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(RoomSearch);

modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    // Do things with data coming from modal, for instance :
    console.log(data);
});

modal.present();
```

And this in your modal controller, to close the modal :

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss({"foo" : "bar"});
```